# Why does this simple Mongoose.js program freeze while doing a 'nested' save?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

**[edit]: I updated the previous question with this, using a very specific reproducible example.**

This is my entire program. 
 
I create two Schemas `ASchema` and `BSchema` with collections `A` and `B` respectively, make two objects `a` and `b`, and attempt to save them sequentially - that is, first `a` then `b`.

```
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

ASchema = new Schema({
    text: String
});

BSchema = new Schema({
    val: Number
});

A = mongoose.model('A', ASchema);
B = mongoose.model('B', BSchema);

a = new A({text: 'this is a'});
b = new B({val: 5});

a.save(function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err.message);
    else {
        console.log('saved a : ', a);
        b.save(function(err) {
            if(err) console.log(err.message);
            else {
                console.log('saved b : ', b);
            }
        });
    }
});

mongoose.disconnect();
```

**What I expect should happen:** 
It should print `saved a :` followed by the document a, and then `saved b :`, followed by the document b.
**What actually happens:** 
It prints `saved a :  { text: 'this is a', _id: 4ee4cab00d2c35fc04000001 }` and nothing more. The program does not stop either; it stays 'stuck'.
Looking through the mongo shell, I find that a collection `as` (`a` pluralized by mongoose, that is okay) has been created, and I can see saved document in it with `db.as.find()`. However, I cannnot find a collection `bs`.
**Tweak:** 
In the saving code, swapping the places of `a` and `b` (order of saving) causes `b` to be saved, and `a` to not be saved. So the problem is not specifically with `a` or `b`.
**Question:** Why does it not save the next document?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be from this code, which looks perfectly ok. I think there may be an error with agent or something like that. Can you console.log it?

Comment: It's not a problem with the person/agent, because swapping their places in the code causes the same effect - it always hangs when saving the 'inner' thing.

Comment: edited the example with something more general, can be tested by anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is very simple, look at your last line:

```
mongoose.disconnect();
```

You shouldn't be doing that, since there are still queries that need to be processed and you don't know when (in our case it's the second query). So what happens is the first query gets executed, Mongoose disconnects and it hangs the second query.

**Solution**

Delete the last line on put `mongoose.disconnect();` after the last query gets executed.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot that line was there

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.disconnect();  //Do not do this as async methods keep running in background.
```

Don't open + close a connection for every query.

Open the connection once, and re-use it.

I do prefer following way:

```
MongoDBconObj.open(function(err, db) {
    //re-use db 
    // All your application codes goes here...
    //..
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
    console.log("HTTP is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 ");
  });
```

See the link for best practice

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-mongodb-native/5cPt84TUsVg